# jmeter 3.2 Http Test Script Recorder port field truncated

Tags: jmeter

Http Test Script Recorder has a port number text box but it is too narrow to enter anything? Has anyone noticed this in new version as works fine in 3.1 and port text box displays correctly

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to others. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is quite broad for me:

[image: JMeter HTTPS Test Script Recorder]

If for some reason default port of `8888` doesn't play for you I can think of the following workaround:

1. Open `recording.jmx` file (lives under "bin/templates" folder of your JMeter installation) with your favorite text or XML editor
2. Locate the following string:

   ```
   <stringProp name="ProxyControlGui.port">8888</stringProp>
   ```
3. Change it to the port of your choice (the "good" range is between 1025 and 65534)
4. Save the file
5. Prepare JMeter  for recording using the changed template by choosing `File -> Templates -> Recording` from JMeter's main menu and clicking "Create"

[image: JMeter Recording Template]

Hopefully "Start" button is big enough to be clicked.

References:

- [Create Test Plan from Template](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#template)
- [How to Save ‘Loads’ of Time Using JMeter's Template Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

Comment: awesome was bit aware if the new version. by the way jmeter is a super tool

Answer (score 0):

Switch to JMeter 3.3 which has fixed this bug and many others of 3.2:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60995

See release notes:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

> Bug 60995 - HTTP Test Script Recorder: Port field is very small under some L&F